# Site does not exist for a2ensite

Tags: system-installation, apache-virtualhost

During the koha installation process I told ubuntu to

```
sudo a2ensite library
```

and got the message

```
ERROR: Site library does not exist!
```

I looked it up and found here that I might have to [rename the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591889/site-does-not-exist-error-for-a2ensite). So I used

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/library /etc/apache2/sites-available/library.conf
```

and got

```
mv: cannot stat '/etc/apache2/sites-available/library': No such file or directory
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem? I use ubuntu 22.04 for desktop.

Comment: check whether /etc/apache2/sites-available/ actually exists any files called library, library.conf or anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add `ls /etc/apache2/sites-available` to your question